# How to run execute scripts in a terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I'm trying to write and execute some scripts from a mac terminal window. 
As an example, I have a file under 
/users/Bob -> test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PATH
```

I'm trying to run this file from the terminal window by just calling "test". I've seen ppl call functions from terminal window without the "./" and I would like to know how. 
Also can the functions be written only in a .sh file or can it also be python or ruby scripts.

Thank you

Comment: try `bash /users/Bob/test.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to run this file from the terminal window by just calling "test".

No, that wont work. `test` will be searched in the internal set of commands or the executables in the `$PATH`. Since `test` happens to be a built-in, you'd feel like it has been executed but without any output.

> I've seen ppl call functions from terminal window without the "./" and I would like to know how.

By, setting the executable bit, putting the file in one of the folders in `$PATH`, and if its a script, by making sure the first line (shebang) is correct.

> Also can the functions be written only in a .sh file or can it also be python or ruby scripts.

It can be written in any language, just ensure the above, and the shebang: `#!/path/to/whatever/executes/this/script` is correct.